# What is the source of my ArrayOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, exception

Here is my code, the point of which is to write a program that randomly inputs 20 numbers from 1 to 10 into a 2-D array of 5 rows and 4 columns. The program should output the 2-D array, and the sum of each row and the sum of each column. I can't figure out where I'm getting this exception (here's my total output):

```
Project 3...
2D Array elements:  6, 6, 7, 10, 4, 4, 0, 9, 0, 1, 3, 10, 1, 10, 10, 9, 10, 5, 8, 2, 
Sum of Rows: 115
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at arrayProject.projectthree(arrayProject.java:96)
    at arrayProject.main(arrayProject.java:19)
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void projectthree(){
    System.out.println("Project 3...");
    /*Write a program that randomly inputs 20 numbers from 1 to 10 into a 2-D array of 5 rows and 4 columns.
     The program should output the 2-D array, the sum of each row storing numbers in a parallel array and
     the sum of each column storing numbers in a parallel array*/
     int array[][] = new int[5][4];
     Random randomizer = new Random();
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
            array[i][j] = randomizer.nextInt(11);   //Assign random values to each element in the array
        }
     }
    System.out.print("2D Array elements: ");
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(" " +array[i][j]+ ",");    //Output 2D Array
        }
     }

    int[] sumOfRows = new int[array.length];
    int[] sumOfColumns = new int[array[0].length];

    int sumR = 0;
    int sumC = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < array[0].length; col++){     //Sum of rows
        sumR += array[row][col];
        }
    sumOfRows[row] = sumR;
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Sum of Rows: " + sumR);


    for(int col = 0; col < array.length; col++){
        for(int row = 0; row < array[0].length; row++){
            sumC += array[row][col];
            }
    sumOfColumns[col] = sumC;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of Columns:" + sumC);

}
```

Comment: Which line is line `96`?

Comment: Runs fine for me.  But in the last for loop, don't you want array[row].length instead of array[0].length?

Comment: In addition to the comments about debugging and reading the stacktrace, it is never too early to get into the habit of writing methods that do one thing and do it well. If your code had such methods, it would be trivial to find the source of your bug.

Comment: @pearbear: Have you silently changed your post since you first asked the question? Your last loop - the one with the problem - has changed since you asked it, making my answer look incorrect. If you're going to change the question, *please* make that clear...

Comment: @JonSkeet no, I have not...
 I am in a class so they want me to re-write methods. I'm a beginner..
 No, I can't use a debugger in my class

Comment: @pearbear: Oops - hadn't scrolled down far enough...yes, the error is still there.

Comment: @AmirAfghani: Are you sure you ran *all* of the code, including the last loop? (You have to scroll to see it...) It definitely throws an exception.

Comment: I see - I didn't run it all apparently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this loop:

```
for(int col = 0; col < array.length; col++){
    for(int row = 0; row < array[0].length; row++){
        sumC += array[row][col];
        }
```

You're accessing `array[row][col]` but you should be accessing `array[col][row]`... or change the way you're looping. Compare this loop with all the others which have worked:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
        System.out.print(" " +array[i][j]+ ",");
    }
 }
```

Note how here `i` runs from 0 to `array.length - 1`, and is used as the first bit of indexing in the expression `array[i][j]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to debug this fairly easily yourself...
The problem is in your last nested for loop...

You say `sumC += array[row][col];` ,
but your row variable is declared on the inside of the loop, you need to switch it to

```
sumC += array[col][row];
```